# setting up signed cookies for aws cloudfront https with php SDK

Tags: php, cookies, https, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sdk

I am setting up a HLS streaming service through cloudfront and implementing several security measures for content protection. I have successfully made it work under http, I can stream video and watch it in my website with a lot of content protection security measures.  For more details on how I managed to make it work for http you can consult it in a post I made in drupal.org about [secure hls streaming](https://www.drupal.org/node/2672400).

But now I need to add https to the formula because some encryption keys for hls encrypted segments are being transmitted, but I am having problems. Now I am working to add https to the formula. I have added a certificate to my site and I have added a different certificate in cludfront because my certificate is not a wildcard one.

My site certificate works for subdomain.mydomain.com

My cloudfront certificate is for *.mydomain.com

My cloudfront distribution has a cname of cdn.mydomain.com

When I create the cookie I set the secure parameter to true in the call (6th parameter after domain):

```
setcookie($name, $value, strtotime('+1 hour'), "/", ".mydomain.com", true, true);
```

But when I try to access some test data in my site

```
if (readfile('https://cdn.mydomain.com/privacy_test.txt')==0)
    print "Error in cdn access";
```

I don't see the contents of the file in my website, but the error message.

So it seems I need more things to do to make cloudfront aws signed cookies work under https. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Simply setting the `$secure` parameter of `setcookie()` does not create a *signed cookie*. The process to create a signed cookie is a bit complicated. First, review [Using Signed Cookies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html), specifically the **Canned** and **Custom** policy sections. You will need to familiarize yourself with [creating a Policy, base64encoding that Policy and creating a Signature from the encoded policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreateURL_PHP.html).

Leveraging the code examples outlined in [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreateURL_PHP.html), I then use the following code in a few of my applications to set the cookies:

```
public static function getCustomSignedCookies()
{
    $domain = '.' . explode('.', apache_request_headers()['Host'], 2)[1];
    $dt = new DateTime();
    $dt->add(new DateInterval('P1Y')); // 1 year
    $expires = $dt->getTimestamp();
    $url = Config::get('cloudfront_url') . '/*';
    $policy = self::getCustomPolicy($url, $expires);
    $encodedPolicy = self::url_safe_base64_encode($policy);
    $signature = self::getSignature($policy);

    $cookies = [
        [
            'name' => 'CloudFront-Policy'
            , 'value' => $encodedPolicy
            , 'expires' => $expires
            , 'path' => '/'
            , 'domain' => $domain
            , 'secure' => true
            , 'httpOnly' => true
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'CloudFront-Signature'
            , 'value' => $signature
            , 'expires' => $expires
            , 'path' => '/'
            , 'domain' => $domain
            , 'secure' => true
            , 'httpOnly' => true
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id'
            , 'value' => self::$keyPair
            , 'expires' => $expires
            , 'path' => '/'
            , 'domain' => $domain
            , 'secure' => true
            , 'httpOnly' => true
        ]
    ];

    return $cookies;
}

public static function setCloudFrontCookies()
{
    ob_start();

    foreach (self::getCustomSignedCookies() as $cookie)
    {
        setcookie
        (
            $cookie['name']
            , $cookie['value']
            , $cookie['expires']
            , $cookie['path']
            , $cookie['domain']
            , $cookie['secure']
            , $cookie['httpOnly']
        );
    }

    ob_end_flush();
}
```

Comment: How does an application set the cookies on Amazon’s domain, though? Even if we create our own A record, isn’t every request to that domain routed to their CloudFront CDN servers? Is the cookie set when their servers proxy some requests back to our origin servers or what? Meaning some of the URLs on that domain hit our PHP and set the cookie, which is then used to load or stream static resources *from that same domain*? Can you please explain this part?

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak you cannot issue cookies for Amazon's cloudfront domains. You must add a custom domain to your cloudfront distribution. The custom domain must have the same root domain as the domain on the websites you want to serve the cookies from. For example, I have `my.website.com` and `my-cdn.website.com`. On my.website.com I create the cloudfront cookies for the `website.com` domain, which leaks into `my-cdn.website.com` requests. More info on this cookie domain weak integrity can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookies-between-subdomain-and-domain